# Selectable date filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, backbone.js

I created a simple app with Backbone and [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/). In a view I created an onRender function.
    I created a page that displays a Report with a date filter, using a select tag and affect to an input when the select tag is chosen. 
    I made that with Backbone and JQuery. And for date I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Pikaday.js](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday).

**This is a part of my code**

```
var selectdate = $('#publicdate',this.el)[0];
selectdate.addEventListener("change",function(){
    var value = selectdate.value;
    var date1 = $('#date1',this.el)[0];
    var date2 = $('#date2',this.el)[0];
    if(value==="today"){
        date1.value = moment().add('days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add('days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        $(date1).attr('disabled',true);
        $(date2).attr('disabled',true);
    } else if(value==="yesterday"){
        date1.value = moment().add(-1,'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add(-1,'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        $(date1).attr('disabled',true);
        $(date2).attr('disabled',true);
    } else if(value==="thismonth"){
        date1.value = moment().add('month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add('month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')

        $(date1).removeAttr('disabled',true);
        $(date2).removeAttr('disabled',true);
    } else if(value==="lastmonth"){
        date1.value = moment().add(-1,'month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add(-1,'month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        $(date1).attr('disabled',true);
        $(date2).attr('disabled',true);
    }
})
```

Is that code is already clean? Is there another way to make that code shorter? Like using a function or something.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, please state only code purpose in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jQuery

Your code uses jQuery, but you don't seem to be using any features of jQuery that offer any advantages over the DOM - unless you need to target older browsers you can remove your jQuery dependency and thus make your code better: faster (less abstraction, fewer dependencies to download), more portable, more future-proof, etc).

Simply replace `$("#id")` with `document.getElementById` and `$(selector)` with `document.querySelectorAll` (you can alias it for brevity if necessary: `var q = document.querySelectorAll;`).

### Time-safety

The `moment()` function, when called, returns the current time value the moment the function is called - your code keeps on calling the `moment()` function which could return different values each time it's called (if there's a long-enough delay in the interpreter, or if your code executes on a time-unit boundary) - issues like these can cause bugs if midnight at the end of a month happens while your function is executing.

For this reason, you should get the value of "now" only once, at the start of your function, and perform all operations on that value (you should treat it as an immutable value too, even though `Date` is mutable, as that's best-practice).

```
var now = moment();
// ...
date1.value = now.add('days').format('yada');
```

#### Culture-sensitivity

You're using the `dd-MM-yyyy` pattern - only a few countries use dashes between the components and it is not ISO-8601 compliant. If this is intentional then that's fine - but if your users are coming from a variety of different countries (with their own date-formatting preferences) then you have two choices:

1. Use ISO-8601 (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) which is unambiguous and as a bonus: is lexicographically sortable.
2. Use Moment's built-in localization ("i18n") support: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

To respect your users' settings, do this:

1. Get `moment-with-locales.js` from their website
2. Modify your initialization code:

   ```
   // Get the ISO culture settings for the current user, e.g. "en-US" or "es-MX":
   var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

   // Configure moment:
   moment.locale( locale );
   ```

When using locales, use the "locale formats" rather than specific formats. Moment uses `"L"` to denote a "numeric date" (e.g. "09/07/2016" in en-GB, "07/09/2016" in en-US, or "2016-07-09" in ISO-8601).

### Everything

So your code would become:

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
moment.locale(locale);

var selectDate = document.getElementById('publicdate');
selectDate.addEventListener('change', onSelectDateChange);

function onSelectDateChange(e) {
    var date1 = document.getElementById('date1');
    var date2 = document.getElementById('date2');
    var now = moment();
    if( selectDate.value == "today" ) {
        date1.value = now.add('days').format('L');
        date2.value = now.add('days').format('L');
        date1.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        date2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else if( value == "yesterday" ) {
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel you made  a point for jQuery with 'everything', the disabling could be done with. `var dates = $('#date1,#date2'); dates.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: @konijn `dates.setAttribute(...` will not work since `setAttribute` is vanilla JS methods. And instead of `attr()`,  `prop()` should be used when setting properties with Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

1. As jQuery is loaded, why not taking advantage of it. This will make the **code short**. In the OP code, Vanilla JS is used and that object is wrapped in jQuery which is not necessary. Just use jQuery with selector.
2. Use an object, that'll be used to keep the mappings of the values and their corresponding configuration of `moment`. This will be easy to add new values.
3. Use `on()` to bind event on the element
4. Combine the similar code. Ex. for `toady` and `yesterday` and `thismonth` and `lastmonth` code is similar. This can be combined with making the difference dynamic.
5. Use chaining to call multiple methods on the same element, instead of diving into DOM multiple times.

```js
var mappings = {
    today: {
        diff: 0,      --| Difference between today and today
        unit: 'days'  --| is 0 days
    },
    yesterday: {
        diff: -1,     --| Difference between toady and yesterday
        unit: 'days'  --| is -1 days
    },
    thismonth: {
        diff: 0,      --| Difference between today and this month
        unit: 'month' --| is 0 month
    },
    lastmonth: {
        diff: -1,     --| Difference between today and last month
        unit: 'month' --| is -1 month
    }
};

$('#publicdate').on('change', function () {
    // Get value of selected option
    var value = $(this).val();

    var startDate,
        endDate;
    var now = moment();
    var map = mappings[value];

    if (value === 'today' || value === 'yesterday') {
        // Startdate and enddate are same
        startDate = endDate = now.add(map.diff, map.unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    } else if (value === 'thismonth' || value === 'lastmonth') {
        startDate = now.add(map.diff, map.unit).startOf(map.unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
        endDate = now.add(map.diff, map.unit).endOf(map.unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    }

    if (startDate && endDate) {
        // Update values and disable the elements
        $('#date1').val(startDate).prop('disabled', true);
        $('#date2').val(endDate).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

---

To make this more small, the mapping can be moved into HTML. The `diff` and `unit` can be added on the elements using custom  `data-*` attributes.

Here's the live Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#publicDate').on('change', function() {
    // Get value of selected option
    var value = $(this).val(),
      $selectedOption = $(this).children(':selected');
    var diff = $selectedOption.data('diff'),
      unit = $selectedOption.data('unit');

    var startDate,
      endDate;
    var now = moment();

    if (value === 'today' || value === 'yesterday') {
      // Startdate and enddate are same
      startDate = endDate = now.add(diff, unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    } else if (value === 'thismonth' || value === 'lastmonth') {
      startDate = now.add(diff, unit).startOf(unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      endDate = now.add(diff, unit).endOf(unit).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    }

    // Update values and disable the elements
    $('#date1').val(startDate).prop('disabled', true);
    $('#date2').val(endDate).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="publicDate">
  <option value="today" data-diff="0" data-unit="days">Today</option>
  <option value="yesterday" data-diff="-1" data-unit="days">Yesterday</option>
  <option value="thismonth" data-diff="0" data-unit="month">This Month</option>
  <option value="lastmonth" data-diff="-1" data-unit="month">Last Month</option>
</select>

<div>Start Date:
  <input id="date1" />
</div>
<div>End Date:
  <input id="date2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Combining JQuery Selectors

Jquery can select multiple items at once as you can with css selectors. This can cut out some duplication.

### 2. Using Switches instead of if-else chains

Switches are a nice way to make if-else (on a single var) chains look more appealing. *(There are some minor caveats but they're not worth mentioning here.)* As you're changing the behavior based on the value of 'value', you can switch on this variable.

### 3. Using a variable to prevent repeated calls of 'moment()'

```
var selectdate = $('#publicdate',this.el)[0];
selectdate.addEventListener("change",function(){
var value = selectdate.value;
var date1 = $('#date1',this.el)[0];
var date2 = $('#date2',this.el)[0];
var bothDates = $('#date1, #date2');
var now = moment();
bothDates.attr('disabled', true);
switch(value)
{
case "today":
    bothDates.value = now.add('days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
break;
case "yesterday":
    bothDates.value = now.add(-1,'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
break;
case "thismonth":
    date1.value = now.add('month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    date2.value = now.add('month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    bothDates.removeAttr('disabled', true);
break;
case "lastmonth":
    date1.value = now.add(-1,'month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    date2.value = now.add(-1,'month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
break;
}});
```

Comment: The "thismonth" case is incorrect based on the original code (removeAttr). Writing a an alternate solution without explanation isn't considered a good answer, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Try to explain why you wrote the code this way.

Answer (score 1):

Good question,

there is so much repetition in there, violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I think the first thing is that you apply a number of things to both `date1` and `date2`, you can capture both of them with something like `var bothDates = $('#date1, #date2');`

The second thing is the constant repetition of `$(date1).attr('disabled',true);`. I assume there is a free selection choice in `publicdate` and try to remove repetition that way.

Furthermore;

- You should try to stick to 1 type of quotes, I think most folks use single quotes.
- Always lowerCamelCase: `selectdate` -> `selectDate`
- You provide `this.el` as a context, if you do this because the `date1` id is not unique, then you have to redesign your page if you want to have a clean design. If `date1` is unique, then I would not provide that context and always use the jQuery `val` functionality.

I would go for something like this:

```
var selectDate = document.getElementById('publicdate'); //Assuming the ID is unique
selectDate .addEventListener("change",function(){
    var value = selectDate .value,
        date1 = $('#date1',this.el),
        date2 = $('#date2',this.el),
        bothDates = $('#date1, #date2');
    bothDates.attr('disabled',true);
    if(value==="today"){
        bothDates.val( moment().add('days').format('DD-MM-YYYY') );
    } else if(value==="yesterday"){
        bothDates.val( moment().add(-1,'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY') );
    } else if(value==="thismonth"){
        date1.value = moment().add('month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add('month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')    
    } else if(value==="lastmonth"){
        date1.value = moment().add(-1,'month').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        date2.value = moment().add(-1,'month').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    } else {
        bothDates.attr('disabled',false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `#id` selectors work globally and don't need a parent element in `$()`
2. Use jQuery fully and don't touch the underlying DOM elements and events.
   Note that `attr('disabled', false)` is the same as `removeAttr('disabled')`
3. Avoid repetition of constants like the format string
4. Don't reinitialize `moment()` each time, reuse the value.

```
$('#publicdate').on('change', function() {
    var now = moment();
    var format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
    var selector = $(this).val();
    switch (selector) {
        case 'today':
        case 'yesterday':
            $('#date1, #date2')
                .val(now.add(selector == 'today' ? 0 : -1, 'days').format(format))
                .attr('disabled', true);
            break;
        case 'thismonth':
        case 'lastmonth':
            var month = now.add(selector == 'thismonth' ? 0 : -1, 'month');
            $('#date1').val(month.startOf('month').format(format))
            $('#date2').val(month.endOf('month').format(format))
            $('#date1, #date2').attr('disabled', selector == 'lastmonth');
            break;
    }
});
```